# Server 2012 Shared Drives

Tags: windows-server-2012, network-share, share, drive

I am trying to access a Shared Drive on box that is running 2012 and I'm getting an error:

Windows cannot access `\\drivexyz\D`

You do not have permissions to access `\\drivexyz\D`.  Contact your network administrator.

Apparently I am the network admin on this box (not my expertise).
I've removed the drive and re-added it.  I've changed the permissions from RO to RW.  I've added "Everyone" to the permissions.  Nothing has worked.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting a link as an answer is frowned upon but the question is really a very novice Windows question.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/keithmayer/archive/2012/10/21/ntfs-shared-folders-a-whole-lot-easier-in-windows-server-2012.aspx#.UkGdqz_-Vi4

You can follow that guide for 2012 and be just fine.

Sharing a drive/folder/path usually follows:

1. share the drive/folder/path with the proper "Share level" permissions
2. Set the proper NTFS level permissions on the folder(s)/file(s) themselves in that "Share"
3. Test and confirm the share

Comment: you are 100% right!  I am admittingly a novice in this area.  I appreciate the link.  I was able to follow along and I am no longer getting the message.  It is now asking me for my credentials and it won't accept it for some reason.  Any thoughts on that?

Comment: If it is asking for credentials, then the one you are currently logged in as doesn't have rights (check "effective permissions" directly on the server share/folder).  Make sure you have given that user both share level AND file/folder level permissions.  Also check "net use" from a cmd line and either remove existing connections or simply log off the workstation and back on and test again.